# How to display the icons and not the text on a mobile view without extra markup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

I am trying to see if there is an efficient way to display only the icons and not the text when viewed in mobile view. I only want to display the icons and not the text like 'Previous' or 'Next'

Her is my HTML:

```
<router-link v-if="myprevLink" :to="'/' + myprevLink">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Previous
</router-link>
    <span class="disabled" v-else
      ><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Previous
    </span>

<router-link v-if="mynextLink" :to="'/' + mynextLink">
      Next <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
</router-link>
    <span class="disabled" v-else>
      Next <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </span>
```

The one way I was thinking was to add a span and put my text in there and then use media queries. Like this:

```
<router-link v-if="myprevLink" :to="'/' + myprevLink">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i><span class = "activePrevLink"> Previous</span>
</router-link>
    <span class="disabled" v-else
      ><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i><span class = "disabledPrevLink"> Previous</span>
    </span>

<router-link v-if="mynextLink" :to="'/' + mynextLink">
      <span class = "activeNextLink">Next</span><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
</router-link>
    <span class="disabled" v-else>
      <span class = "disabledNextLink">Previous</span><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </span>
```

But doing this way, I am creating 4 of these span tags . Is there a better way to do is and improve this current HTML?

Comment: As you need to wrap them to declare that their content needs to be hidden at a mobile view, all alternatives would look similar.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add span tag you can acheive it using css media queries and visibility property like this.

```css
        @media(max-width:600px) {

            router-link,
            .disabled {
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            i::after,
            i::before {
                visibility: visible;
            }
        }
```

```html
<router-link v-if="myprevLink" :to="'/' + myprevLink">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Previous
</router-link>
    <span class="disabled" v-else
      ><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Previous
    </span>

<router-link v-if="mynextLink" :to="'/' + mynextLink">
      Next <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
</router-link>
    <span class="disabled" v-else>
      Next <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </span>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because, I want to remove only the text in mobile view but keep the icons. This CSS you mentioned hides everything(icons and the text) when the link is disabled. Also, when the link is active I still want to keep the icons but not the text.